# Pile-up events in collider experiments and the average number of interactions

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, particle-accelerators

Is the average number of interactions a measure of the amount of pile-up events (pollution background events to hard-scatter events)? if not, why is always presented as an indication and how accurate is it?

Comment: For people interested see this for pile up meaning https://cms.cern/news/how-cms-weeds-out-particles-pile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Pile-up is when two or more events happen "at the same time" in a detector, where the exact definition of "at the same time" will depend on your detector and your particular consideration. The average number of interactions is an indication of just that, events per time. Its accuracy is given by Poisson statistics.

Comment: Yes, the more events per unit time, the higher the probability that two of them occur in a time window where your measurement system will think they are one event.

Comment: Thank you very much @rfl